# Title of run.bat

Tags: batch-file, server, minecraft

I currently own a minecraft server. And right now I have 5 worlds that work at the same time.
The issue is, that each of them is named as pinned [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SoJn.png).
I was wondering if there is any possibilty to add something to the [run.bat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri4Pv.png) file, so that the Title will be automaticaly changed to certain Title?

Comment: You want to change the `title`? Do you can think of a reasonable name for a command that could change the `title`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example about how to run a minecraft server in batch with custom title :

```
@echo off
title My MC server
java -Xms2G -Xmx32G -jar paper-1.17.1-90.jar nogui
```

Result:

[image: working]

PS: Don't include code as image. Prefer copy/paste

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
@echo off   
cls  
echo This script will keep your server running even after crashing!  
title Server Restarter By ProBuildz846  
:StartServer  
start /wait java -Xmx1G -jar SERVER_FILE_NAME.jar nogui -o true  
echo (%time%) Server closed, restarting!  
goto StartServer
```

This code will restart your server after it closes